# SpringBoot annotationProcessorPaths not allowed in pom.xml on IntelliJ

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am trying to setup `mapstruct` processing plugins and IntelliJ is highlighting the `annotationProcessorPaths`. It says it is not allowed here. Below is my build

```
   <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>
```

Comment: What version Maven are you using?

Also, it looks like it's supposed to be                          <annotationProcessorPath> under                         rather than <path> under <annotationProcessorPaths>

Answer (score 0):

I get same error, but I solved.

**Step #1 Erase "build" section on pom.xml**

**Step #2 Maven Clean Package**

**Step #3 Add following code block to pom.xml**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Step #4 Maven Clean Package, then run application, then stop it.**

**Step #5 Add missing fields to pom.xml**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>1.18.30</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                        <version>0.2.0</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <compilerArg>
                        -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
                    </compilerArg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```